# How to enforce Dirichlet boundary conditions using FEM without knowing surface nodes?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

Consider the problem

\begin{align}
\Delta u &= f \;\text{ in } \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \\
u &= g \;\,\text{on} \; \,\partial \Omega
\end{align}

Suppose I have a tetrahedral mesh of $\Omega$ and a triangle mesh  of $\partial \Omega$. If the surface mesh and the tetrahedral mesh aren't related (e.g. they were generated separately, one is more refined etc.) are there any methods to enforce essential BCs?

Natural BCs seem straightforward since an integral over the surface isn't related to the volume mesh. I've heard that it's possible to impose essential boundary conditions in the weak formulation, would this be a way forward?

OR

Is the only possible way to extract the surface nodes of the tetrahedral mesh and then apply BCs to the stiffness matrix?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I'm also curious about the case when your surface is represented implicitly/parametrically. Are there any algorithms besides generating a surface mesh/conforming volume mesh?

Comment: Just to be clear, the nodes in the boundary mesh are not found in the volume mesh?

Comment: @Dylan, correct the set of nodes of the volume mesh and the nodes of the surface mesh are disjoint. For example maybe the volume mesh is generated from a binary test of a scalar field and the surface mesh is generated from some iso-surface extraction algorithm like marching cubes, dual contouring, etc. I'm aware of methods to generate volume meshes from surfaces meshes.

Comment: Isn't there a way to extract the boundary information from the the volume mesh? I think MATLAB can do that

Comment: I have trouble understanding how the finite element basis can be even defined in such a scenario. Is this a hypothetical question or do you have an implementation of this?